# CSS background-image not working

Tags: html, css, background-image

I don't know what is going on but it seems that the background image isn't loading.

test.html:

```
<div class="pToolContainer">
     <span class="btn-pTool">
         <a class="btn-pToolName" href="#"></a>
     </span>
     <div class="pToolSlidePanel"></div>
</div>
```

style.css:

```
    .btn-pTool{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-image: url(slide_button.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    }

    .btn-pToolName{
        text-align: center; 
        width: 26px; 
        height: 190px; 
        display: block; 
        color: #fff; 
        text-decoration: none;  
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  
        font-weight: bold; 
        font-size: 1em; 
        line-height: 32px; 
    }
```

By the way the image does exist in the folder of test.html.

Comment: are style.css and slide_button.png are in the same folder?

Comment: yes they are in the same folder

Comment: can you see image by writing http://imagepath/slide_button.png?

Comment: write something between <a> </a> and check if it is working any thing just for check

Answer (score 5):

Add "display:block;" in your .btn-pTool class

Answer (score 4):

Use shorthand property for the background property and type the folder name where thje image had been located.

```
.btn-pTool{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background:url("../folder name/slide_button.png") no-repeat; 
            }

.btn-pToolName{
    text-align: center; 
    width: 26px; 
    height: 190px; 
    display: block; 
    color: #fff; 
    text-decoration: none;  
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  
    font-weight: bold; 
    font-size: 1em; 
    line-height: 32px; 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I faced this problem. My html was as below:

```
<th style="background-image:url('Image.png');">
</th>
```

I added "&nbsp" as @shankhan suggested inside th and the image started showing up.

```
<th style="background-image:url('Image.png');">
   &nbsp;
</th>
```

Comment: I also face this problem and use your way to solve it. However, why should I add a `&nbsp`, then the image shows up ?

Comment: @CYB: I am not an expert. But I believe empty cells are hidden by default. You may add a css like `table {
empty-cells:show;
}` as told [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6828615/740756)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `display:block` OR `display:inline-block`

Try giving sufficient `padding` to your `.btn-pToolName` and **make sure** you have the correct values for `background-position`

Comment: I don't undesrtand.. Can someone leave a comment while down voting?

Answer (score 0):

@TheBigO, that's not correct.  Spans can have background/images (tested in IE8 and Chrome as a sanity check).

The issue is that the a.btn-pToolName is marked as display: block.  This causes webkit browsers to no longer show the background in the outer span.  IE seems to render it how the OP is wanting.

OP chance the .btn-pTool class to be display: inline-block to make it work like a span/div hybrid (take the background, but not cause a break in the layout).

Comment: IE8 and Chrome might allow you to give backgrounds to spans, although that is not part of the CSS spec -- so they are just being forgiving. You should comment on my answer, instead of posting a new answer to respond to me :)

Comment: I don't have enough "cred" on this stackexchange site (I do on startups) to comment.  Plus I also gave an alternative to your answer.  Also... the spec might say one thing, but reality is another.  It's great and all to code to a spec, but I live in the real world... :)

Comment: The point is not to "code to spec" on principle alone. The assumption we make with the spec is that browsers other than IE and Chrome, and possible future browsers, will follow the spec. That's what it's there for. Especially with so many web-enabled phones these days, you shouldn't make the assumption that spans will always have a background. Why not follow the spec when it's just as easy?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <span class="btn-pTool">
 <a class="btn-pToolName" href="#"></a>
 </span>
```

That's empty. Try adding a non breaking space to give the link and span some contents:

```
 <span class="btn-pTool">
 <a class="btn-pToolName" href="#">&nbsp;</a>
 </span>
```

It's also worth noting that the CSS spec says that you can't give a span a background image because spans are not block elements. Put the background image code in the div's class style, or use `<p> instead of <span>`. Some browsers might let you put a background in a span, but not all will (perhaps older versions of IE).

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code and found that if we put `background-image: url(image.png);` in `btn-pToolName` and change `color:#000000`. it displays the image at background.

my test css:

```
           .btn-pTool {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            .btn-pToolName {
                text-align: center;
                width: 26px;
                height: 190px;
                display: block;
                color: #000000;
                text-decoration: none;
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-weight: bold;
                font-size: 1em;
                line-height: 32px;
                background-image: url(defalut.png);
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
            }
```

and test html:

```
        <div class="pToolContainer">
            <span class="btn-pTool"><a class="btn-pToolName" href="#">adad</a></span>
            <div class="pToolSlidePanel"></div>
        </div>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have applied class "btn-pTool" to span which is an inline element... give `display:block` to it and also add some text inside the`<a>` tag and the see the result.

Also give a background color and background position as well to the image though default background position is there.. but try doing it this way

Answer (score 0):

Use this one to add background---

```
background-image: url('images-path');
```

You can also add repeat or no-repeat function in it!

```
background: url('images-path')   no-repeat 00;
```

Comment: `background-image` will break if you include position and repeat information. I believe you wanted to use `background` in your second line.

Answer (score 0):

```
<span class="btn-pTool">
         <a class="btn-pToolName" href="#"></a>
     </span>
```

Try to add `display:block` to `.btn-pTool`, and give it a width and height.

Also in your code both tbn-pTool and btn-pToolName have no text content, so that may result in them not being displayed at all.

You can try to force come content in them this way

```
.btn-pTool, .btn-pToolName {
    content: " ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below works. Replace the text within the **single quotes** with your image name. If it is in the same folder, if not add **../foldername/'yourimagename'** I hope that helps.

**NOTE:**

*use of the single quotes by most of the programmers is not advised but I use it and it works. Also, if you would write a PHP you would appreciate what it can do i.e. add the background image automatically from the variable etc.*

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.btn-pTool{
margin:0;
padding:0;
background-image: url('your name of the field');
height:100px;
width:200px;
display:block;
}

.btn-pToolName{
    text-align: center; 
    width: 26px; 
    height: 190px; 
    display: block; 
    color: #fff; 
    text-decoration: none;  
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  
    font-weight: bold; 
    font-size: 1em; 
    line-height: 32px; 
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="pToolContainer">
    <span class="btn-pTool"><a class="btn-pToolName" href="#">Test text</a></span>
    <div class="pToolSlidePanel">Test text</div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is that, copy and past this background-image: `url(../slide_button.png);` instead of `background-image: url(slide_button.png);`
In such case we need to use ../ before path.
Either you need to give full path.
One other thing is that, in case before doing any change just clear the browser history and then refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

1.Use this code in stylesheet

```
body {
  background: URL("slide_button.png");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no repeat;
```

2.Put img and html file together in single folder
3.IF not worked try converting png file to jpg for that just upload pic on facebook and then download that pic from facebook it will automatically converted into jpg and while uploading tick mark private setting so that ur friends cant view that image
4.if still not work imform me..