# How to be able to show Table TD's without text in them

Tags: html, css, html-table

**My Question:**
How can I leave a Table its TD without text, without making it disappear.

I use this HTML code:

```
<div id="push_down"></div>

    <div id="global_wrapper">
       <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="sep_table">
           <tr>
              <td id="side_1"></td>
              <td id="main"></td>
              <td id="side_2"></td>
           </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
```

And this CSS code:

```
html, body {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

#push_down {
    padding-top: 53px;
}
#global_wrapper {
}
#sep_table {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 100%;
}
#side_1 {
    background:url(../images/navbar-bg-left.jpg) center repeat-x;
    height:78px;
}
#main {
    background:url(../images/navbar.jpg) center no-repeat;
    height:33px;
    width: 989px;
    padding-top:45px;
}
#side_2 {
    background:url(../images/navbar-bg-right.jpg) center repeat-x;
    height:78px;
}
.navbar{
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#FFF;
}
.navbar a:link{
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.navbar a:visited{
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.navbar a:hover{
    color:#131313;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.navbar a:active{
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

With css:

```
table {
empty-cells:show;
}
```

In html (not really clean):

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: If there is &nbsp; in the cell, then it should work everywhere.

Comment: @Ixecube - try adding Ixecube `border-collapse: collapse` to fix chrome.

Comment: @easwee Thats not working, im gonna keep the transparent image solution. Seems to work the best, thanks for the help though :)

Comment: @Ixecube It actually works with no problems with or without border-collapse - you must have something interfering with your style. Check sample test page: http://www.easwee.net/css/emptycelltest/

Answer (score 1):

You can also put a transparent image (like a .png image) with `1px height` and `1px width`.

Photoshop uses `space.png` as a auxiliar image on table containers when save for web and devices, you can copy this idea.

Remember to put at this same image the `height and width 100%`, to fill all the table cell.

Answer (score 0):

you can add this style:

```
td{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: That would make all tds a fixed height- he probably doesn't want that.